# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transaction') --> when I try to write to indexedDB when offline

Tags: javascript, try-catch, typeerror, indexeddb, offline-caching

I'm trying to get my app to use indexedDB when there is no internet connection. I have an idb.js file that sets up the object store and then defines a saveRecord function that I use in another js file:

```
let db;

const request = indexedDB.open('pizza_hunt', 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    const db = event.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore('new_pizza', { autoIncrement: true });
}

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    // when db is successfully created with its object store (from onupgradeneeded event above) or simply established a connection, save reference to db in global variable
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        // uploadPizza();
    }
};

request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.errorCode);
};

// This function will be executed if we attempt to submit a new pizza and there's no internet connection
function saveRecord(record) {
    const transaction = db.transaction(['new_pizza'],'readwrite');

    const pizzaObjectStore = transaction.objectStore('new_pizza');

    pizzaObjectStore.add(record);
};
```

But when the function is called in the other file, I keep getting the error from above, that .transaction is undefined and it doesn't write anything to the new_pizza object store.

Here's the context in which it is called (another js file). It all works unless the catch is triggered:

```
const formData = { pizzaName, createdBy, size, toppings };

  fetch('/api/pizzas', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(postResponse => {
      alert('Pizza created succesfully!');
      console.log(postResponse);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      saveRecord(formData);
    });
```

Comment: This seems like an issue with non-blocking, aka, async code. you need to learn about the concept of non-blocking javascript before continuing to develop in indexedDB. There are many other answers to similar questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: For example, review these questions and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bindexeddb%5D+async